# Toolbar overlapping contents

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Need help figuring out why my toolbar is overlapping the contents. 
I have a toolbar layout here

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I then use this toolbar with a navigation drawer like so.

navigation_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.jlurena.yougothw.activities.base.NavigationDrawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_list"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee">
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Finally, so I would only have to extend a NavigationDrawer.java I set up the toolbar in NavigationDrawer.java and extend it in every other activity I'll need. I then inflate it like so

```
public void inflateBaseLayout(Activity activity, int resLayoutId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // Inflate Navigation Drawer in activity
        View view = inflater.inflate(resLayoutId, null, true);
        drawer.addView(view, 0); // Where drawer is the DrawerLayout from navigation_drawer.xml
    }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong with the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to put the `DrawerLayout` and `Toolbar` inside a container such as a `LinearLayout` because DrawerLayout as the root hovers over (overlaps) other contents.

I changed my navigation_drawer.xml to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="me.jlurena.yougothw.activities.base.NavigationDrawer">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nav_list"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee">
        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the `ListView` into the `LinearLayout` after the include for the toolbar. That should bring everything in order.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it got me thinking about the actual DrawerLayout.